# viewController lifecycle

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, instantiation, lifecycle

Apple's documentation says "When a segue is triggered, it causes a new view controller to be instantiated and transitioned onscreen." Some behavior I'm seeing has me questioning if the VC is actually destroyed and recreated each time the view is seque'd to.

In my application each time I seque to a particular view I note that the  the following viewController function is called (which is consistent with the VC being recreated each time it is sequed to):

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
```

Note, this viewController is also a datasource for it's collectionView and has a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *messages;
```

And every time initWithCoder is called I alloc and init a messages array and assign it to the above pointer.

When I navigate back to another view and then seque back again I'm seeing strangeness that has me thinking that the VC might be being re-used.  Or alternately if the first instance wasn't destroyed and can still receive notifications.

The first thing that is strange is that in viewDidLoad if I call addObserver:self for a particular notification which I want this VC to handle then the second time I seque into this VC I will get two notifications sent to the VC's notification handler for every notification sent.  This is consistent with the VC being reused otherwise why would the handler get called twice?

But going against this re-use scenario is that initWithCoder is in-fact being called the second time the View is loaded.

Since I don't want 2 or more notifications generated for every notification post, I use a static boolean to guarantee that addObserver is only called once.  I.e. addObserver is only called the first time viewDidLoad is called, and not subsequent times.

viewDidLoad and notification handler access the messages array.  On the second seque, viewDidLoad seems to access a newly alloc/init'd messages array but when the notification handler accesses messages it seems to be the previous messages array from the previous time the VC was loaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are unregistering yourself as an observer on those specific keys once the view is being dismissed.  You might have old method still being performed because they were never unregistered.

Comment: Yes I actually thought about this while at dinner and I think it must be that the notification center is holding a strong reference to the viewController.